# Cannot connect CouchDB 3.3.2 with Clauseau 2.21.5

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, couchdb-3.x

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 with CouchDB 3.3.2 and trying to marry couch to Clauseau 2.21.5.

All installation seems to be according to the guides. However, whenever I run

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5984
```

I'm getting the following in the Clauseau log:

```
[executor:2] ERROR scalang.node.ServerHandshakeHandler - Exception caught during erlang handshake:
scalang.node.ErlangAuthException: Peer authentication error.
        at scalang.node.ServerHandshakeHandler.verifyChallenge(ServerHandshakeHandler.scala:80)
        at scalang.node.ServerHandshakeHandler$$anonfun$3.apply(ServerHandshakeHandler.scala:49)
        at scalang.node.ServerHandshakeHandler$$anonfun$3.apply(ServerHandshakeHandler.scala:47)
        at scalang.util.StateMachine$State.event(StateMachine.scala:39)
        at scalang.util.StateMachine$class.event(StateMachine.scala:22)
        at scalang.node.HandshakeHandler.event(HandshakeHandler.scala:28)
        at scalang.node.HandshakeHandler.messageReceived(HandshakeHandler.scala:49)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:302)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:76)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:302)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:321)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:299)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:216)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.ChannelEventRunnable.run(ChannelEventRunnable.java:69)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor$ChildExecutor.run(OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor.java:316)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        at overlock.threadpool.ErrorLoggedThread.run(NamedThreadFactory.scala:40)
[executor:2] INFO scalang.node.ErlangHandler - channel disconnected org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext@397ca55c [id: 0x7574d4f1, /127.0.0.1:59532 :> /127.0.0.1:37157] DISCONNECTED. peer: null
[executor:2] ERROR scalang.node.ServerHandshakeHandler - Channel closed during handshake
```

Also **search** does not appear in **features**:

```
{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"3.3.2","git_sha":"11a234070","uuid":"e0f4acf1191ee7034b5491d5e8bf8068","features":["access-ready","partitioned","pluggable-storage-engines","reshard","scheduler"],"vendor":{"name":"The Apache Software Foundation"}}
```

Is there something I'm missing with the setup?

Comment: same issue found in https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/4369

Answer (score 1):

Got it working! (CouchDB - v3.3.2 and Clouseau - v2.21.6)

What I have done to fix this

Clouseau folder

Remove file: slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar

Add files: slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar, slf4j-simple-2.0.7.jar (Download from https://download.jar-download.com/cache_jars/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/2.0.7/jar_files.zip)

change in file clouseau.ini

cookie=monster (change monster to we can get cookie value from \etc\vm.args setcookie's value)